# Data on disk is not directly updated with the 'Update' functionality on my recordset

Tags: vba, adodb

I am working on some VBA macros. I also use ADODB.Recordset to access data in my Access database.

Now, I need to loop through records in my table and in this loop, also need to update the same table in another function.

Here is the code (cleaned for easy reading).

```
Dim strSql As String
Dim rstCycles As adodb.Recordset

strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblCycles WHERE DatePlanning = #" & dteCurrentDate & "#"
Set rstCycles = SelectQuery(strSql)

 While Not rstCycles.EOF

    if ... then
       rstCycles("NoCycle1") = ...
       rstCycles.Update
    end if

    RefreshPlanning (*)

    rstCycles.MoveNext
 Wend
```

(*) In this function I perform a select on the tblCycles table.

The problem is after the rstCycles.Update, the data is not immediately record on disk thus the call to RefreshPlanning does not read updated data. If I set a '1 second pause' after the update everything is ok. I don't want to use a kind of pause in my loop. Is there another solution?

UPDATE ---------------

RefreshPlanning is a simple function to refresh my excel sheet based on my tblCycles table.

```
Sub RefreshPlanning(DatePlanning As Date, CodeEquipement As String)

   Dim strSql As String
   Dim rstCycles As adodb.Recordset

   strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblCycles WHERE DatePlanning = #" & DatePlanning & "# AND CodeEquipement = '" & CodeEquipement & "'"
   Set rstCycles = SelectQuery(strSql)

   While Not rstCycles.EOF
      ' Some code here to update my excel sheet
      ' ...
      rstCycles.MoveNext
   Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are working with Access and VBA why are you not using DAO? It is many times faster with Access.

Comment: This is too late to swap from ADO to DAO (except if have a solution on my problem only with DAO). Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset ...

Answer (score 0):

DAO is many times faster than ADO with MS Access:

```
Dim strSql As String
Dim rstCycles As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = OpenDatabase("z:\docs\test.accdb")

strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblCycles WHERE DatePlanning = #" & dteCurrentDate & "#"
Set rstCycles = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)

 While Not rstCycles.EOF

    if ... then
       rstCycles.Edit
       rstCycles("NoCycle1") = ...
       rstCycles.Update
    end if

    ''Need more information here
    RefreshPlanning (*)

    rstCycles.MoveNext
 Wend
```

If dteCurrentDate  is the same as today, you can say:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblCycles WHERE DatePlanning = Date()"
```

Comment: You are right: I do a test and DAO is MUCH more faster than ADO but unfortunately it doesn't solved my problem explained above. Maybe there is a kind of trick (flush, no cache, ...) with DAO to directly write data on disk?

Comment: Unfortunately your code has been so far reduced that I cannot see what you are doing. I thought the code sample I posted showed you how to change your posted example to take advantage of DAO. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is: in my loop I do (1) an update of the data and (2) just after the update I call another function (where I do a select of the same data.) --> If I don't pause after the update the select does not see updated date. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: As I said above `Need more information here:  RefreshPlanning (*)` I believe you can use DAO in your function and you will not have a problem with a delay. It is also possible that you can speed up the ADO, but you have not provided enough information to say one way or the other.

Comment: I updated my question to show you what RefreshPlanning looks like.

Comment: You are going to have to say what you are doing. Excel has suddenly come into the picture. There are numerous ways to check Excel and you may not have chosen the best. Are you working in MS Access?

Comment: Oops sorry, I thought I explained in my question that my VBA macros was in an Excel workbook. Realy sorry about that. My fault. So I have an Excel workbook with VBA and aside I have an Access database (no form, only data).

Comment: In that case, I suspect you need to tidy up your code if you want to get some speed. It is not possible to say from the information provided what you can do when you are constrained by various limits, such as ADO. It may be best to use different SQL or a different order or events.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll investigate.